# Problema con Mysql y Entity Framework (The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string)

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, entity-framework-6, orm

Buen día comunidad, cree una pequeña aplicación para hacer un test de velocidad de consultas a bse de datos MySQL con un ORM (Dapper) ya luego quice hacer una comparación usando Entity Framework, anteriormente ya había lo había usado con SQL Server y no me dio problemas, hice los procedimientos que aparece en la documentación de MySQL para poder hacer las consultas con este pero al querer hacer la consulta se lanza una excepción: "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string"

Hasta donde tengo entido para usar Entity Framework hay que descargar ciertos paquetes nuget con las mismas versiones, tengo descargado 3 de ellos para usar mysql:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí adjunto el código que estoy usando para crear el contexto de la base de datos, para ello estoy mandando como parámetro la cadena de conexión:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class testDbContext :DbContext
{
    public testDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<entities.productInfo> product { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<entities.saleInfo> sale { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<entities.creditInfo> credit { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<entities.saleDetailInfo> saleDetail { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Esta es la clase que uso para poder hacer las consultas, en el constructor paso como parámetro la cadena de conexión y hago una instancia de la clase DbContext y asigno los DbSet de las tablas que quiero usar en esa clase:

```
public class entityFrameworkData
{
    private dbContext.testDbContext context;
    private DbSet<entities.creditInfo> creditTable;
    private DbSet<entities.saleDetailInfo> saleDetailTable;

    public entityFrameworkData(string connectionString)
    {
        context = new dbContext.testDbContext(connectionString);
        creditTable = context.Set<entities.creditInfo>();
        saleDetailTable = context.Set<entities.saleDetailInfo>();
    }

    public async Task<List<entities.DTO.creditDTO>> getCreditsDTO(int customerId)
    {
        try
        {
            var credits = await creditTable
                .Include(c => c.sale)
                .Where(c => c.status == true && c.sale.idTypePayment == 2 && c.sale.idCustomer == customerId && c.sale.status == true)
                .Select(c => new entities.DTO.creditDTO
                {
                    id = c.id,
                    totalToPay = c.totalToPay,
                    paymentDate = c.paymentDate,
                    isPaid = c.isPaid,
                    dateSale = c.sale.entryDate,
                    idSale = c.sale.id
                })
                ?.ToListAsync();

            return credits;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"GetCreditDetailedEntitiesByCustomerId: { ex.Message }");
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de ejecutar la función getCreditsDTO es cuando me lanza la excepción, estuve revisando si el detalle esté en mi app.config, pero sólo agregué los nodos que se muestra en la documentación de MySQL, no asigné la cadena de conexión ya que esa la paso como parámetro (incluso la agregué para ver si daba error pero aún persistía):

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System">
        <section name="DevExpress.LookAndFeel.Design.AppSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
</applicationSettings>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
</startup>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
             type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Hasta ahora no he podido buscar el error, ya le di muchas vueltas al app.config pero nada, desconozco por que sea el error, la versión de entity framwork que estoy usando es la 6.4.4 y la versión de mysql que tengo instalado en mi equipo es la 8.0.27.0 mismas que la versión de dll de mysql que descargué, espero que me puedan ayuda ya que llevo algunos días atorado con esto.

Adjunto una captura de la excepción
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Los errores varían dependiendo el proveedor de datos.
Estas acciones podría ayudarte a solucionar el problema:

1. Asegúrese que el servicio de MySQL esté ejecutando.
2. Asegúrese que la cadena de conexión sea correcta.
3. Si problema sigue existiendo, intenta degradando o actualizando los paquetes de NuGet.
4. Si estás empezando con EntityFramework, te recomiendo leer la documentación de Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/

Hay varios modos de conectar con un proveedor de datos, todo depende del alcance del proyecto.
[Usar Entity Framework 6 con una base de datos existente (Ejemplo).](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database)

Comment: Bajé la versión de Entity Framework a la 6.2 (estaba usando la versión 6.4) y ya funciona, gracias por el consejo, aúnque está raro que esté dando error con la nueva versión.